# Conteo n repeticiones en lista enlazada

Tags: java, lista, algoritmos, nodos

Tengo un método para contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un nombre en una lista enlazada.
Para eso uso un método, Contains, para ver si lo tiene, pero no me funciona me retonar 0 y debería retornarme 3, adjunto mi código.

```
private int countNames(SinglyLinkedList list, String name){
       SinglyLinkedList aux = list;
       int count = 0;
        try {
            if(aux.contains(name)){
                aux.remove(name);
                count++;
            } // If
        } catch (ListException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SinglyLinkedListNGTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } // Try - Catch
        return count;
    } // Fin método
```

Ese es mí método para contar la cantidad de veces, SinglyLinkedList está llena de Students, que tienen varios atributos, yo le paso la lista por parámetro junto con el nombre que quiero buscar.
Con remove lo borro, por eso hago otra lista auxiliar, los elimino para que no cuente el mismo nombre más de 1 vez.

Ahora adjunto mi método contains.:

```
public boolean contains(Object element) throws ListException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new ListException("SinglyLinkedList is empty");
        } // If
        Node aux = first;
        while (aux != null) {
            if (util.Utility.equals(aux.data, element)) {
                return true;
            } // If
            aux = aux.next;
        } // While
        return false; //indica q el elemento no existe
    } // Contains
```

También adjunto mi método equals.

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    switch (instanceOf(a, b)) {
        case "integer":
            Integer x = (Integer) a;
            Integer y = (Integer) b;
            return x.equals(y);
        case "string":
            String s1 = (String) a;
            String s2 = (String) b;
            //return s1.compareTo(s2)==0; //OPCION 1
            return s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2); //OPCION 2
        case "student":
            Student student1 = (Student) a;
            Student student2 = (Student) b;
            return student1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(student2.getName());
    } // Swicth
    return false; //en cualquier otro caso
} // Equals
```

Comment: Hace rato que no programo en Java pero noto ciertas inconsistencias en el código.
Por ejemplo, en "countNames" al hacer aux = list estás asignando la referencia al objeto, por lo tanto al modificar uno estarías modificando también el otro. en "contains" la variable "first" no está declarada, y en equals creo que "instanceOf()" es un constructor que recibe una clase como segundo parámetro (probablemente debas usar la palabra reservada "instanceof") y además le estás enviando al método un objecto de la clase Student y un String pero después tratás ambos parámetros como si fuesen del mismo tipo.

Comment: Sumado a lo que ya mencionaron que el método isEmpty() al no recibir ningún parámetro probablemente devuelva `true`.

Comment: Parece que reinventas la rueda en `Utility.equals`, mejor haz `Student implements Comparable`. Sólo tu sabes que hace el método `Utility.instanceof(? a, ? b)` y no me imagino qué esperar de resultado. ¿El objetivo de `contains()` es poder comparar *"peras con manzanas"*?.

Comment: instaceof es un método para saber si los elementos por parametro son un entero, string u objeto. @Sal

Comment: @N.N. isEmpty solo cuenta la cantidad de valores de la lista, está dentro de la misma clase de la lista, no retorna true porque ya la llené. Ahora cómo podría entonces comparar el atributo name del objeto con la String?

Comment: Deberías actualizar la pregunta para que tenga el código mínimo necesario para que podamos entender cómo funciona. Por ejemplo, desde dónde se llama `countNames` y qué es lo que hace `instanceOf`.

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude resolverlo de una manera mucho más sencilla. Adjunto la respuesta.

```
private int countNames(SinglyLinkedList list, String name) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            Node aux = list.getNode(1);
            while (aux != null) {
                 Student a = (Student) aux.data; 
                 if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(a.getName())){
                     count++;
                 } // If
                 aux = aux.next;
            } // While
        } catch (ListException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SinglyLinkedListNGTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } // Try - Catch
        return count;
    } // Fin método
```

Answer (score -2):

Recuerda revisar bien el funcionamiento de los métodos, por lo general siempre se genera estos problemas, debes recordar que los tipos de métodos isEmpty son de tipo booleano por lo que no estas haciendo la comprobación y no esta entrado al condicional debería ser del tipo

```
if(isEmpty() == true){}
```

y del mismo modo el método contains es de tipo boolean por lo que la comprobación debería ser igual

```
if(aux.contains(name)==true){}
```

Si tienes este tipo de problemas recuerda revisar la documentacion

Un saludo.

Comment: en realidad cuando un método es booleano si lo dejo if(isEmpty()) esa condición es siempre que isEmpty sea true va a entrar, saludos.

Comment: Claro, pero tocaría de todos modos verificar para que tipo de situaciones deseas, pruébale con la implementación que te mencione y puede que se soluciones, en varias ocasiones he tenido los mismo problemas.

Comment: @nicolasromero No, este no es el problema, además es redundancia en el código. ¿porqué deberías evaluar `true == true` o `false == true` que simplemente te retornarían el mismo valor que ya tenías pero gastando más recursos?

Comment: ¿Te fijaste si imprime algo el logger?

Comment: En el caso en el que quieras comprobar que el valor de una lista sea diferente de vacío  y se cumpla cierta condición, repito, he usado de forma normal el método isEmpty y no ha funcionado hasta que haga la comprobación

Comment: @N.N. me imprime el count en 0

Comment: @N.N. No encuentra semenjanzas, debería imprimir un 3 pero imprime un 0

Comment: Me refiero al logger que está en el catch. Podés probar imprimiéndolo en consola sino.